# criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()) returns empty list

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, projection, indexoutofboundsexception

i'm getting a `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0` **sometimes** when executing this code:

```
Criteria crResult = getSession().createCriteria(XXX.class);
[...]
crResult.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
Integer countResults = ((Integer)crResult.list().get(0)); // <---This gives the error
```

Is there any case in that `crResult.list()` can return an empty list?

(Just a clarification, i'm not talking about receiving a list with an occurrence of 0 results, i'm talking about receiving an **empty list**)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you can just use:

```
crResult.uniqueResult()
```

I dont think you can get a null list, but you can get a list with 0 items in some cases, in which there is no `.get(0)` index and throwing the error you're getting...

You can also just check the list length first then get the item:

```
List<?> list= crResult.list();
if(list.size>0)
    countResults = (Integer)list().get(0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You say that "you can get a list with 0 items **in some cases** ". Do you know what cases can be? maybe an error with the database conection?

Thank you!!

Comment: Besides a query without any match, i had never experienced any weird scenario, i have seen ppl not aware of joins doing 0 matches thus resulting in a 0 items list, and some other claiming something weird happening to the session (like trying to reuse a session after a hibernate exception), but those scenarios are very spesific to the way you handling your session or your transactions.